# What is the best way to deal with temporary directory and workspaces while processing bigger rasters?

Tags: r, raster, temporary-directory, terra

As large workspaces have been occupied by the temporary folder, I indexed to the folder in the remote desktop referencing solutions from R-help and in my case using `terraOptions` this way:

`terraOptions(tempdir = "/processing/tmp_terra/")`

I cropped a raster (took 6 hours) and saved it as a file name `LA_crop.tif` to another folder with a different name.
I loaded the saved raster in the new session:

```rb
myRaster <- rast(“/home/shared/om/data/rasters/LA_crop.tif”)
myPolygon <- vect(“/home/shared/om/data/polygons/PA.gpkg”)

# Now, while performing other operations like: 

r <- rasterize(myPolygon, myRaster, myPolygon$ID)

# I am getting this error:
Error: [rasterize] file does not exist: /tmp/RtmpiiUwq0/spat_jprtedxq260WQLq.tif

# Everytime I run the code, the name of tmp file in error part gets changed:
Error: [rasterize] file does not exist: /tmp/RtmpnyTR6l/spat_MpDvnvNP26auyqt.tif

sessionInfo()
# R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
# Running under: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
```

But, when I perform similar operations taking an example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67025225/append-extent-of-big-spatraster-object-to-match-the-extent-of-spatvector-to-com/67027780#67027780), it works fine.

```rb
library(terra)
# terra version 1.1-4
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)

z <- rasterize(v, r, "NAME_1")    
zonal(r, z, mean, na.rm=TRUE)

#  zone      elevation
#1    0       403.1779
#2    1       283.8853
#3    2       316.1935
```

1. What am I doing wrong here? Is it because I changed the temporary directory?
2. Any further suggestions on how to deal with this problem efficiently (future reference).

Comment: Not sure if it would help but have you tried the [dev version on GitHub](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/commits/master)? There have been several changes since the CRAN version was released

Comment: Thank you for your comment @tung. I tried with dev version too i.e. `terra 1.1-9`. The problem was still there till yesterday but when I checked today it was solved and the weird thing is I don't know how. It would be great if somebody could have a blog or article on **efficient and smart way to deal with big rasters in R**.

Comment: The problem is now back again. And also I just find out that there are already many blogs on big spatial data handling in R.

Answer (score 0):

What you refer to as `"file"` is in fact

```
"/tmp/RtmpiiUwq0/spat_jprtedxq260WQLq.tif"
```

That file is in a temporary folder created by R. Such folders are removed when a session ends. You state however, that you saved the file elsewhere. If that is the case, you should use that file.

Comment: Thank you @Robert for your feedback. With your comment, I made few edits to my question. I hope it is somewhat clear now as compared to previous one. I am stuck here in this part for few days and tried using `package::raster`, which is running since 13 hours, having a terrible waiting experience.